# How does the thunderstorm from Plant-fed Lightning Reeds choose targets?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-2

What are the rules/algorithm by which the thunderstorm generated by feeding Plant Food Upgrade to  The Lightning Reeds targets its victims?

Random? Closest? Leftmost?

Answer (score 3):

I've done extensive testing on this, and can say with confidence that it is 100% random. If you have a specific zombie you would like to target, using it on a lightning reed is going to be a gamble unless there are very few zombies in play.